# Проверить наличие .25

Tags: php

Как правильно проверить есть ли в цифре .25?

К примеру:

```
0.25
1.25
2.25
6
7
8.50
```

Нужно проверить, присутствует ли .25? Регуляркой наверное это говноедство.

Comment:     if( floor($x) == $x - 0.25) { // мама, у меня есть четверть!

Отрицательные бывают?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Точная проверка подразумевает, что число при совпадении у нас равно х.25 и ничему другому

```
if (fmod(number, 1) === 0.25) {
    ...
}
```

Неточная обращается с числом, как со строкой и ищет именно совпадение .25 (при этом подпадет 2.2566, скажем)

```
if (strpos((string) number, '0.25') !== false) {
    ...
}
```

при этом, скорее всего, потребуется `number_format()`, чтобы избежать представлений типа 1E+15. Ну и по факту это действительно что регуляркой, что простым поиском - одно и то же.

Впрочем, первый вариант можно модифицировать, чтобы он работал, как второй:

```
if (($mod = fmod(number, 1)) < 0.26 && $mod > 0.24) {
    ...
}
```